# Godeps vs Vendor System in Go

Tags: go

I read lot of docs about Go Dependency Management and I understand there are two systems for Go to manage them:
* 1.5 System and before
* 1.6 and later

The problem both try to address is: **how to create a reproducible build with all the dependency at the exact commit level expected?**

The first one basically has a **Godeps** folder with **Godeps.json** files where are reported the list of dependencies with their own commit level.
Then with a command a developer can easily recreate the same dev environment.

The same thing happen with vendor system. This time we have a **vendor** folder with **vendor.json** file.

Now at my eyes these two systems look similar and it's not clear to me why the new system has been introduced. They apparently do the same thing and it's not clear to me which problem the first system had that second system solved.

Can someone explain to me this? Can someone also explain a real example that is problematic with first method and the second resolve?
Thanks

Comment: Vendoring is a mechanism (introduced in v1.5), and godep is one of multiple implementations to automate it. You can copy-paste vendored dependencies manually. godep, glide and other tools just help to automate managing it.

Comment: That was clear to me. But why introduce in 1.5 as experiment feature the vendor system when there was already the method with Godeps and Godeps.json. Moreover, they looks like very similar so it's not clear to me why the new system was introduced. Obviously, everything change if you tell me that the Godeps system simply became the official method to manage dependencies and Google simply renamed it with vendor. Is this true?

Comment: The `vendor` folder is a method baked into the core Go tooling, especially the `go` tool. It was an official experiment to see if vendoring works, what works well and what needs to be changed. github.com/tools/godep is a (unofficial) tool which does roughly the same. There is an new upcoming tool github.com/golang/dep which will be some kind of "official" dependency management tool.

Comment: I have to admit I do not understand what you are asking. Different people and different groups/communities have been working independently on some problem and the found different solutions. There are more ways and tools to manage Go dependencies than the vendor folder and godep and that is okay. " the Godeps system simply became the official method to manage dependencies and Google simply renamed it with vendor" this is completely wrong. As said: There are probably around 10 ways to do it, vendor and godeps being just two. Hopefully this mess will consolidate and converge to `dep`.

Comment: Your first answer satisfy me. It is exactly what I am expecting and it fits with what I learned so far. If you copy and past it in the Answer I'll accept it as an answer.

Comment: Only another question. Was Godeps Godeps.json system introduced by godep utility? If so, How could a developer before the introduction of godep recreate a dev environment with dependencies at a specific commit level if godep didn't exist? I know these question seems strange but I am creating a doc with some historical info that will be later required to justify some design decision.

Comment: One subtlety that is often not clarified is the question of what to put in VCS (git etc). So you have a tool that fetches particular versions of many dependencies so that the source code is local. But then what? To some, just having local copies of known versions is sufficient. To others, these local copies ought to be added to your own VCS too. There are many tools to do the first job. But whether the second step is necessary has been a topic of discussion.